# can't navigate to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm newbie. There is a button in ViewController.m . When I press the button it has to navigate to SecondViewController but SecondViewController doesn't appear.

And at the SecondViewController on the navigation bar, there will be "Back" button to go back to ViewController. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

ViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

    EnglishViewController *v = [[[EnglishViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"EnglishViewController"
                                bundle:nil]
                               autorelease];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:TRUE];
}
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**The solution (depends on @George's answer):**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navCon =[[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                      initWithRootViewController:self.viewController]
                                     autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController =navCon;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is the first viewcontroller in the navigation controller?

Comment: ViewController is the first ViewController. EnglishViewController is the second ViewController

Comment: Than you should surrond ViewController with navigationcontroller to make it work. I shall unswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `ViewController` in `AppDelegate.m` you must surrond it with `navigationController` to make it work

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    [navigation release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nothing even the first view doesn't appear. I add the AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function to the question. UINavigationController was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The first few things to check: is your `-buttonPressed` method actually getting called? Is are you getting and passing a non-nil value to `-pushViewController:animated:`? Is `self.navigationController` actually non-nil when you make that call?

Your code looks fine as written.

Comment: Yes it is calling. I did the connection at xib for buttonPressed. Maybe the problem is that I didn't do anything about delegate but I don't think that I need it because there will be no sending data eachother.